# How do I reference the filename (when using parsefile) from with XML::Parser's START handler?

Tags: xml, perl

If I instantiate an XML::Parser:

```
$parser = new XML::Parser(ErrorContext => 2, Namespaces => 0);
$parser->setHandlers(Start => \&start_handler);
```

And then call parsefile:

```
$parser->parsefile($filename);
```

Is it possible to retrieve the value of `$filename` from within `start_handler`?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the guts of XML::Parser my suggestions is to use a closure:

```
my $filename = "foo.bar";
my $start_handler = sub { 
    # ues $filename here
};
$parser = new XML::Parser(ErrorContext => 2, Namespaces => 0);
$parser->setHandlers(Start => $start_handler);
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me because parsefile is called recursively, but is pretty close.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A clumsy way to tackle this is to wrap the `parsefile` method in a subfunction `parse_file` (see below) and store the filename in a `$current_filename` (this is similar to [gensym's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16905587/7920), but tolerant of recursion).

```
$parser = new XML::Parser(ErrorContext => 2, Namespaces => 0);
$parser->setHandlers(Start => \&start_handler);

$current_filename = '';
$previous_filename = '';

parse_file($filename);

sub parse_file {
   $previous_filename = $current_filename;
   $current_filename = shift;
   $parser->parsefile($current_filename);
   $current_filename = $previous_filename;
}

sub start_handler { 
...
... $current_filename ...
...
}
```